# Keeping all WordPress environments in sync

Tags: wordpress, workflow

[image]

**What are your approaches** to keep all environments in snyc? Of course not every part should be synced e.g. config files, user tables and other custom settings.

Do you have solutions that are hassle free and are straight forward?

I know that there are plugins that help with that task but do you have solutions that won't rely on plugins? I know some use git to delpoy code changes but how do handle content changes?